# Application Crashed while parsing HTML link & which parser is best hpple or Objective-C-HTML-Parser?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am using **hpple** to parse data (body content) from a html link in this way:

```
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData]; 
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"body"];
```

it got crashed, so I have change search tag to `@"<body>"`

```
TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:htmlData];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"<body>"];
```

again the application crashed. How can I get the information that is available in body tag & **which parser is best hpple or Objective-C-HMTL-Parser ?**

Comment: I have used TFHpple without any problem. What does the crash log say ?

Comment: I am not getting anything in elements array. When I am trying to access first object in the array it crashed. My question is why I am unable to get body information using TFHpple ??

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
htmlParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:[[responseString stringByDecodingHTMLEntities] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
elements  = [htmlParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//body"];
```

You forgot "//", that indicates search at any depth. Note that in this example I use a great method of [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser); `stringByDecodingHTMLEntities`, which helps me with HTML parsing in XML documents